# Exchange Server 2010 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2010, windows-server-2012

I've just installed Exchange Server 2010 on Windows Server 2008 R2. Can I update windows to Server 2012? Will Exchange work correctly?

Comment: There are far more complexities to this question than you seem to be aware of (What is your Exchange configuration like? Do you have something else like BES involved? etc.) -- We can't just give you a blind "yes" or "no" answer to a question like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking your question is more around what is required from the Exchange 2010 perspective so that it will run on Windows Server 2012 as a suported configuration.

**Answer: Exchange Server 2010 SP3 fully supports running on Windows Server 2012.**